# How to sort database values in descending order with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am bit new to CI.I want to sort my database values in descending order using this query below in my model. However, it doesn't work form me and throw errors .please help me out.

```
   function get_records(){      
    $this->db->from($this->tbl_contactus);
    $this->db->order_by("contactus_id", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

The error: 
[image]

Comment: Your property `$this->tbl_contactus` is empty according to error

Comment: that is impossible it works with //$query = $this->db->get('tbl_contactus');      //return $query->result();

Comment: If you are sure that your property is not empty then add `$this->db->select('*')` before from function's line it is the correct format to write  query with active record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
   function get_records(){

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("tbl_contactus");
    $this->db->order_by("contactus_id", "desc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

and also you can use this

```
function get_records(){

    $this->db->select()->from('tbl_contactus')->order_by('contactus_id', 'desc');

}
```

Comment: You can directly use $this->db->get($tbl_contactus)->order_by('contactus_id',desc)->result();

Comment: $this->db->select()->from('tbl_contactus')->order_by('contactus_id', 'desc'); is also correct

Answer (score 1):

you have to check `$tbl_contactus` because  its not defined or empty in that line

```
  $this->db->from($this->tbl_contactus);
```

You are using query like that:

```
    SELECT * ORDER BY contactus_id ASC
```

while it should be

```
    SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY contactus_id ASC
```